# Add/update item with users information Sharepoint Client C#

Tags: sharepoint, csom, author

Using Microsoft.Sharepoint.CLient & .Runtime.dll ver.16.0.0.0

I have a Item list (Lost packages) with Tracking number(title),Description(currier),MailTo(**Type: Person, Show Field: E-Mail**)
I also have another list (buyers) of available User to pick up from

So from my C# client program I want to add or update an item from Lost packages and with the MailTo -Email- of an user. Right now I can only get the Name as String of the Author of a ListItem. How do I get the user information from a ListItem so I can change the MailTo to a specific user

```
 public Package(ListItem _package) {
        this.item = _package;
        if (this.item != null) {
            this.exist = true;
            this.id = this.item["ID"].ToString();
            this.trackNo =  (String)this.item["Title"];
            this.currier = (String)this.item["Description"];
            this.status = (String)this.item["Status"];

            FieldUserValue userAuthor = (FieldUserValue)this.item["Author"];  
            this.Owner = userAuthor.LookupValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for your reference, just need to set the User Id to FieldUserValue class, then set to MailTo field:

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev");
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("JerryList4");
        clientContext.Load(spList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        ListItem item = spList.GetItemById(3);
        clientContext.Load(item);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        FieldUserValue userValue = new FieldUserValue();
        userValue.LookupId = 19; //set user Id here
        item["MailTo"] = userValue;
        item.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

For the user id, you can get it from this Rest EndPoint:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,LoginName
```

[image]